# How can I define colspan with a tablestructure that uses flex?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

In my react app I am trying to get my head around flexbox. How can I get a colspan in flex? This is part of the react code:

```
<div className="table-row">
        <div className="text"></div>
        <div className="text colspan2"><textarea></textarea></div>
        <div className="text"></div>
      </div>
```

In my app.css I got :

```
.colspan2 {
  grid-area: cell4;
}
```

Is it possible to get a colspan in a flex table?

Comment: FYI: flexbox and grid are two different layout models. If you’re using `grid-area`, that’s not flex.

Comment: As @04FS said, Flexbox ≠ Grid. Chris Coyier has two guides that covers [Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) and [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) quite well over at css-tricks, check them out, you might learn a thing or two.

Answer (score 0):

Colspan is for tables, not for divs controlled by flexbox layout. If the content you're trying to display is table data you should use tables, not divs as that is what they're made for. Chucking out tables for layout means exactly that: don't use tables for layout, it doesn't mean don't use tables ever.

However, if what you're trying to do is simply ad a modifier to a flex child to be twice the width you could do something like this:

```
.table-row {
    display: flex;
}
.text {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.text.colspan2 {
    flex-grow: 2;
}
```